# How do I make Firefox open in the foreground when clicking a link in Thunderbird?

Tags: unity, firefox, thunderbird, window-manager

I click a link in Thunderbird (31.8.0) and Firefox (40) opens, but it's always in the background, even though keyboard focus is transferred from Thunderbird to Firefox. I have been pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice as a workaround for what feels like years, but I'd like to not have to.

I'm fairly certain that Thunderbird isn't the only application from which I have this problem, but even if it was, I feel the question's still legitimate.

How do I fix it?

Comment: This really sounds more like a bug in Ubuntu, which should probably be reported on Launchpad. If the focus shifts to Firefox, but it doesn't come up in front, it doesn't seem like a setting can fix this.

Comment: I've no problem reporting it there: I just thought to check first if there is a setting of some sort...

Comment: That's what we're for. I don't think you did this incorrectly.